# Why i cant place .value attribute as i define the var?

Tags: javascript

```
document.write('<input type="text" id="start" placeholder="start"><br> <input type="text" id="end"><br> <button id ="generate">Click to Generate</button>');
var start = document.getElementById("start"),
    end = document.getElementById("end"),
    myButton= document.getElementById("generate"); 
myButton.onclick = function() {
  "use strict";
  document.write("<select>");
  var years;
  for (years = start.value; years <= end.value; years++){
    document.write("<option value=\"" + years + "\">" + years + "</option>");
  }
    document.write("</select>");
};
```

when i try to put (.value) attribute outside the function it doesn't work like this:

```
var start = document.getElementById("start").value,
 end = document.getElementById("end").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the value of the input elements is blank and you're running this JS on page load. When the `onclick` function is executed, `start` and `end` already contain the values that were there on document load ("" and "")

When you were using the element object, you're fetching the `value` fresh within the `onclick` function, therefore it will retrieve and use the actual values inside of the inputs at the time `onclick` is run.